# Try to prove the inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractional-part

My problem:

> Show that the inequality is valid for all sufficiently large $n$
>
> $$
> \left\lbrace\frac{1}{{1}^{1/3}}+\frac{1}{{3}^{1/3}}+\cdots+
> \frac{1}{{(2n+1)}^{1/3}}\right\rbrace>\frac12
> $$
>
> Where $\{\cdot \}$ mean fractional part function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 2):

This is false.  The infinite series diverges, but the $n$th term goes to $0$.  When all the terms are $<.01$ and the sum first exceeds some large integer $N$, the fractional part will be less than $.01$.